# primeng how to design dropdown like a button

Tags: css, primeng

[image]I am using primeng to design my UI. i want a dropdown look like a button as shown in my attachment. can anyone help how to achieve this?

here is my code:

```
  <p-dropdown [options]="items" placeholder="SORT BY"></p-dropdown>
```

Thanks

Comment: _...like a button as shown in my attachment._ Where is that attachment?

Comment: attachement added. thanks

Answer (score 0):

In actual implementation they are using these css property:

```
.ui-dropdown .ui-dropdown-trigger {
border-right: none;
border-top: none;
border-bottom: none;
cursor: pointer;
width: 1.5em;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
top: 0;
padding: 0 .25em;
```

}

Override the CSS like below .

```
.ui-dropdown .ui-dropdown-trigger{
 border-left:none;
}
```